# Send me SMS when I get an email on my server

Tags: sms, alert, postfix-mta, privacy

I have postfix and dovecot running on a server.  When a certain kind of email comes in for accounts on the domain, I'd like an SMS to go out.  I already set this up for one user using Postfix's BCC mapping and the "SMS email addresses" provided by the tel co.

However, here in the post-Snowden world, with heightened awareness of how easy SMS apparently is to hack, and with potential issues with long emails being sent via SMS, **we want the SMS to just say "you got an email"** or something like that.  We don't want to BCC the entire email message via the SMS system.  That's what email is for; we just want the SMS to be an alert, like the way pagers were used in the old days.  I suspect there should be a way to do this but it might take me days to learn enough about procmail or script piping and postfix gateways to figure it out.

I would be surprised if I was the first person in the world to want to send an SMS alert on email events?

So the BCC is apparently not a problem.  The email-to-SMS is apparently not a problem. The problem is how to modify the body of the BCC'd email, or otherwise how to send a simple SMS alert (or simple email alert) upon certain email events (specifically, when email is received for certain recipients on the server via postfix).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [dovecot's sieve](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve) with `enotify` or `vnd.dovecot.execute`.
Simple `enotify` can deliver exactly what you have asked for.  Dovecot specific `vnd.dovecot.execute` can be used to implement extra protections to avoid turning mail bombing into SMS bombing.

Example from [RFC5435](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5435):

```
require ["enotify"];

if header :contains "from" "boss@example.org" {
  notify :importance "1"
    :message "This is probably very important"
    "mailto:alm@example.com";
}
```